How can I get all of my apps to see all of my drives?
I just moved to Noble Numbat (from Mint 21) and finding issues accessing some of my SATA drives. Files and Libre Office can read/write to all drives but installed apps like Audacity and Audacious see 0 files and report "Permission denied" when I try to access.
Specifics of install:- Clean install of Ubuntu 24.4 Noble Numbat Desktop, after complete erasure of boot drive.
The drives previously operated on Mint.
Specifics of drives, mount locations:-
1.0TB HDD: /dev/sde1 - Mounted at /media/dallas/Blue2
1.0TB HDD: /dev/sdd1 - Mounted at /media/dallas/test
4.0TB HDD: /dev/sda1 - Mounted at /media/dallas/BitBucket1
480GB SSD: /dev/sdc - Mounted at /media/dallas/WorkFiles
960GB SSD: /dev/sdb1 - Mounted at /media/dallas/Musicandmedia

update: Issue resolved... "Most snaps can be configured to have permission to removable media" Thanks, mook765

Some specifics may help us to understand.  Where have you mounted the SATA drives as location of mount can influence the results (eg. confined apps have security restrictions that will allow them to see certain directories, but not see others).   Was this a clean install as there is no direct method to move from a Ubuntu-based system (Linux Mint 21) to a Ubuntu Server/Desktop install.

Please edit your question and paste the results of lsblk | grep -v '^loop'

This is most likely happening because you installed the apps which don't have acces to that drives as snap package. Most snaps can be configured to have permission to removable media. Check first with snap list if the problematic apps are installed as snaps.

Use APT apps instead of snap apps (all apps on the default app store are snap apps)
